# Sparql with Java Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena, wikidata-query-service

I'm using next query in Wikidata Query Service:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>  
PREFIX xsd: <www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>  
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>  

select ?lexemeId ?lemma WHERE { 
?lexemeId <http://purl.org/dc/terms/language> wd:Q1860.
  ?lexemeId wikibase:lemma ?lemma.
FILTER (regex(?lemma, '^bank.*'))
}
```

It works fine when executing at https://query.wikidata.org/ but, if trying using Java Jena, it fails, cause:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Line 7, column 11: Unresolved prefixed name: wikibase:lemma
```

It can't resolve wikibase as a prefix.
Any clue?
Thx in advance, David.

Comment: the error message is quite meaningful: `Unresolved prefixed name: wikibase:lemma` - `wikibase` is not defined among your PREFIX declarations. it works in Wikidata because it's predefined. See the list here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Full_list_of_prefixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use their SPARQL query page a number of prefixes are pre-declared, including wikibase. When querying the endpoint remotely these have to be declared. So use `PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>` in your query.

A list of prefixes is available in the [wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Full_list_of_prefixes)